# Rails duplicate loop - Hash and array loop

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

In my view I have:

```
<% @results.each_pair do |country_code, available| %>
   <% @prices.each do |cc,domain| %>
   <% klass = available.registered? ? "pinfo" : "info" %>
    <span class="<%= klass %>"></span>
    <%= @domain + country_code %>       <%= domain.send(cc) %>$<br />
 <% end %>
 <% end %>
```

And the output is:

```
asdsaddk 8$
asdsaddk 1$
asdsadcom 8$
asdsadcom 1$
```

My controller:

```
def domain
  country_codes = %w[ dk com ]

  @domain = "asdsad"

  @results = { }
  @prices = { }

  country_codes.each do |cc|
    @results[cc] = Whois.whois("#{@domain}.#{cc}")
    @prices[cc.to_sym] = Domain.order(cc).first
  end
  render :layout => false
end
```

How do I create a normal loop like where the output is not duplicate like:

```
asdsaddk 8$
asdsadcom 1$
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace:

```
<% @results.each_pair do |country_code, available| %>
  <% @prices.each do |cc,domain| %>
    <%= @domain + country_code %>       <%= domain.send(cc) %>$<br />
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

With:

```
<% @prices.each do |cc,domain| %>
  <%= @domain + cc.to_s %>       <%= domain.send(cc) %>$<br />
<% end %>
```

Indeed, you don't use the `available` variable from `@results`.

Sidenote: once again, you don't have any array here, only Hashes.

---

Reorganization needed:

```
def domain
  country_codes = %w[ dk com ]

  @domain = "asdsad"

  @output = { }

  country_codes.each do |cc|
    @output[cc.to_sym] = { :whois  => Whois.whois("#{@domain}.#{cc}"),
                           :domain => Domain.order(cc).first }
  end
  render :layout => false
end
```

In your view:

```
<% @output.each do |cc, hash| %>
  <span class="<%= hash[:whois].registered? ? "pinfo" : "info" %>"></span>
  <%= @domain + key.to_s %>       <%= hash[:domain].send(cc) %>$<br />
<% end %>
```

Comment: changed my answer, you needed refactoring

Comment: I get this error with your updated answer: ActionView::Template::Error (undefined local variable or method `cc' for #<#<Cla
ss:0x6e625d8>:0x6e603e8>):